# My boolean keeps getting changed from false to true out of nowhere

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

Somewhere in between the `onCreate()` and `onPause()` method, my `changePage` boolean gets changed from `false` to `true` without invoking any changes to it systematically. Once the `onCreate()` method is called, I press the home button which triggers the `onPause()` method and suddenly the boolean is changed to true. What is going on?

```
 public class Menu extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    Global.changePage=false;
    Global.snd = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bgmusic);
    Global.snd.start();
    Global.btnSound = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tglSound);
    Global.snd.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Global.snd.start();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (Global.changePage){

    }
    else{
        Global.snd.pause();
    }
}
```

The `Global` class looks like this:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class Global {
    public static MediaPlayer snd;
    public static ToggleButton btnSound;
    public static Boolean changePage;
}
```

Comment: Possibly the `super.onPause();` statement reverts back the `Global.changePage` to `true`. Remove it and try again.

Comment: where is Global initialized? And what is in Global?

Comment: I added my Global class to the end of the code section

Comment: Can you comment this " Global.snd.start();" in listener and try again.

Comment: Still returns true after commenting it.

Comment: ok, create getter and setter for changePage, and use debugger with breakpoint and make Global static class

Comment: It wont trigger the breakpoint if its changing on its own so it wouldn't trigger the getter and setter?

Comment: ramaral - it gets called later in a different class but that code is the first time it gets used.

Comment: Accidentally deleted the comment: changePage is static, did you use another instance of Global elsewhere?

Comment: ramaral - it gets called later in a different class but that code is the first time it gets used.

Comment: Look at all lines where the changePage are set to true. The code shown have nothing wrong

Comment: nowhere in my project does it set the boolean to true. only false.

Comment: I changed the boolean to a string and referred to it that way, and it works. Weird.